# How can I make VoiceOver in Xamarin not read out the type of view?

Tags: c#, xamarin, accessibility, voiceover

So - I have an Image that is used as a Button.

```cs
someKindOfButton = new Image
{
   Source = //...
   // stuff like height and width and stuff
};
TapGestureRecognizer tappedImage = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tappedImage.Tapped += TappedTheImage; // a method to change the value the image is bound to
```

I am adding this Image to my accessibility tree

```
someKindOfButton.SetAutomationProperties("Page.Image.someKindOfButton", "click this nice button")
```

But when i focus on this nice button, it reads "Click this nice button - Image".

I am now not sure, why this is and how to not make it read "Image". This is also not a single issue, I also have it read some other widgets in other places I don't want it to, like "Page Title Name - Padding". Some places I want it to be like that, some I don't want it to be like that.

Have I provided enough information to produce a solution? I am relatively new to accessibility and xamarin and am working on an existing project - so if more details are needed please comment them so I can provide them.

Comment: I am no expert of Accesibility, but according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/accessibility/automation-properties) you code should be. `AutomationProperties.SetIsInAccessibleTree(someKindOfButton, true);
AutomationProperties.SetHelpText(someKindOfButton, "click this nice button");`

Comment: Also take into account that surely each element has it's own way to be read by the VoiceOver. Maybe you should use an ImageButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: the best solution would be to use the button instead and assign the image to it. While it will pronounce the 'button' this won't be confusing.

VoiceOver needs to tell the type of the control so that user can be aware of the actions that he can perform. For example if you navigate to the table it is critical to know that it is the table as it has very specific commands that other controls don't support. In some way that is similar to what the person without eyesight problems experience - he knows that it is the table and there is no way you can hide that fact from him.

So as far as I know it is not possible and I think it is not possible for the good reason.

Comment: Well, that's all fun and dandy until you have a clickable image. Why would a clickable image be anounced as image if, in fact, it is used as a button? It is clickable, yet the VoiceOver reads it as Image. If it reads button instead, nice please, tell me how. But this is not the only spot where I don't want VoiceOver to announce the kind of View.

Comment: @MaritnGe You can assign only image to the button and then it will say button in VoiceOver and look like the image on the screen.

Comment: There is no button - the image IS the button. A clickable image. Are you saying the Solution is to put the Image *inside* a button or something similiar?

Comment: @MaritnGe yes. The button has such a property. It doesn't need to have any text, just image though it can have both.

Comment: Prefect, I will do that then! Do you want to edit your answer to suggest that so I can accept it?

Comment: @MaritnGe sure :)